# executing multiple commands in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a command that runs in my bash script;

```
daemon -20 $exec -a  -b $var &
```

I want to use the taskset command with my command multiply;

```
daemon -20 ; taskset -c 0,1 $exec -a  -b $var &
```

Bu it does not work.What is the problem. When I use taskset with echo for example, It works.

It does not work with daemon.

UPDATE: @chepner I think the third method you suggested.It can be done but i prefer not to extract the proc ids again.I used daemon to run as daemon and set -20 to nice value of process.So if there is a way to use taskset to set CPU affinity and nice commands to set priority together, it will also be good

Comment: What has this to do with sed or awk?

Answer (score 0):

The semi-colon separates two distinct processes (think of it as a visible new-line).

When you run `daemon -20 $exec -a  -b $var &`, you are running a single command, `daemon`, which takes (among others) an argument stored in the variable `exec` as the program to run as a daemon.

[ If I guess correctly, you want to start two daemons using the `taskset` command. I think what you want is

```
taskset -c 0,1 daemon -20 taskset -c 0,1 $exec -a  -b $var
```

Update: I guessed wrong! and this seems to have a terrible duplication error anyway, with taskset called twice.
]

There are a few possibilities:

1. `daemon taskset -c 0,1 $exec -a -b $var`, which looks nice, but I suspect is wrong, because it probably makes `taskset` a daemon, not `$exec`.
2. `taskset -c 0,1 daemon $exec -a -b $var`, which is just a slightly corrected form of my previous answer with the extra call to `taskset` removed. I suspect this creates two daemons, which you don't want.
3. Start your daemon as you did originally with `daemon -20 $exec -a  -b $var &`. Next, find the process ID of `$exec` now that it is running. Finally, run `taskset -c 0,1 -p $PID`, where `PID` is the process ID for `$exec`.

The reason I think you need to use #3 is that `daemon` and `taskset` each take a command as an argument and runs that command. Neither one can (easily) act on the command started by the other in a single line as you propose.

---

Your attempt,

```
daemon -20 ; taskset -c 0,1 $exec -a  -b $var &
```

calls `daemon` with just a single argument (`-20`) which may or may not do anything (I'm not familiar with the `daemon` command). After it completes, it calls the `taskset` command to run the executable named in `$exec` on two processors.

Comment: no 2 processes. I want to run a single process   $exec -a  -b $var &
are executable and arguments, think it as process1 args, so i want to run process1 as daemon and set 0,1 cpu cores to it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, so excuse me if this doesn't answer your question.

You could do this:

```
daemon -20 $exec -a -b $var &
taskset -p -c 0,1 $!
```

which will run the daemon command and then immediately set it's CPU affinity, or:

```
taskset -c 0,1 daemon -20 $exec -a -b $var &
```

which starts the daemon with the proper affinity in the first place.

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with the taskset command; this answer is based entirely off my reading of the taskset man page.

Edit: I'm not familiar with what the `daemon` command does exactly. If you merely want to run a command stored in $exec in the background with a given affinity, this should suffice:

```
taskset -c 0,1 $exec -a -b $var &
```